# How to store Mobile Numbers in asp.net Membership c# and SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership, createuserwizard

I have a web application which stores customer details like username, firstname and email address ... etc...etc..

I am using Asp.Net Membership, also my web page where i will allow customers to register I'm using CreateUserWizard.

I would like to know how to save customer mobile numbers using asp.net Membership. In my sql table I have all the asp.net membership tables. However wanted to know how to customize the table to allow mobile numbers to be saved into database.

Any ideas?

---

I Have  Custom UserProfile Class where I have setup the mobile property and other properties. How Can I save all the details into separate columns in database??

public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
    {
        public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
        {
            return Create(username) as UserProfile;
        }

```
    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
    {
        return Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName) as UserProfile;
    }


    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string MobileNumber
    {
        get { return base["MobileNumber"].ToString(); }
        set { base["MobileNumber"] = value; }
    }

    //Few other properties.....



}
```

Here is my webconfig settings

```
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="EXAMPLE" applicationName="EXAMPLE" description="SqlProfileProvider for SampleApplication"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) properties. In web.config add `<profile>` entry.

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="MobileNumber"  />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: ok but do i just add this column onto users table to save the mobile number?

Comment: However I would like to store these mobile numbers onto membership table?? Is that possible?

Comment: If you add a profile variable like AVD suggests, it will be stored automatically for you in the membership and will be tied to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add the Profile property mentioned above and you can access this property by

```
Profile.MobileNumber = "12232";// to Save the Mobile No of current logged in user
```

ProfileProvider will automatically saves this for you in database.